# How can i add data programatically in linqqtosql?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linq, linq-to-sql

i dislike below methods.  Because more fields (suchas 150 fields) it is not good method. There is any SetValue method to add datato sql linqtosql for submitchanges?

```
 MyClass c = new MyClass ();
              c.FirstField = "bvnvb";
              c.......
              c...
              c...

             // Too many rows there is...
              engCtx.MyClass.InsertOnSubmit(c);
              engCtx.SubmitChanges();
```

How can i do with a loop method via using linq?

it is simple request why don't understand it is clear. i don't want to make it above is there any method like below?

```
foreach(...........)
engCtx.MyClass.Add(item);
```

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want to set all the properties of `MyClass`? What are you trying to loop over?

Comment: I realy don't understand what is your problem and what solution do you want :/

Comment: I can only guess you are trying to loop over the properties; then I'm not sure how to loop over the values you want to set?

Comment: Now where did `item` come from?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you want.

The LINQ part of this is only two lines.

The "creating an object the way you want it part" is longer, but it's your object, it's under your control.  Add a ctor which takes a number of parameters.  Add SetXXXX() methods which set a number of properties at once.  (Use partial classes if the main part of tha main is generated)